# Is file caching practically have the same performance as memory caching for a simpler site?

Tags: php, performance, caching

I have a PHP site on shared hosting which uses the database for rendering pages. Most pages are fairly static, so I thought about implementing some kind of caching.

When deciding between file caching and memory caching I often read that modern OSs cache often read files in memory. So does that mean in a simple case (single server) there is no point in implementing a memory cache, because a file cache effectively has the same effect (files read from memory instead of disk)?

Comment: Not sure if this is a SO type question, but for small systems where disk based caching is used, yes the OS may have the file in memory.  For more control on *nix, you can say that certain file systems are memory based (tmpfs).  But this sort of optimisation comes after things like database and app performance (IMHO)

Comment: We would need a lot more information to help you decide the best caching methods or if caching will benefit you at all.